# Desk content on second screen

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I'm on Laptop. I'm on Windows 10, I just make the Windows Update. Yesterday everything was fine.

Now, when I only have my main screen, all desk content are here.
When I connect my second monitor on my computer, it move all desk content (icon, shortcut ...) on it. I check, and it is the second screen for windows but we have all shortcut !

I reboot my computer, and the problem is already here.

I didn't found any problem like me.

Comment: If you press `WIN` + `P`, do you have the option to Extend?

Comment: yes, it's in extend (and when I come on "Only 1", all icon come on first)

Comment: Are you sure your main monitor is set as main monitor? Choose "this is my main display" in settings->display (when you've selected the display there that you want to be your main display). As described here: https://www.cedarville.edu/insights/blog/monitor-dual-screen-setup-for-desktop-computers.aspx

Comment: Yes, i'm sure about that. It's one of the first thing that i checked

Comment: Did you already your **BIOS**? Please, tell us on your question the **laptop and monitor model**.

Comment: "Did you already your BIOS?" ? I have not check it. And on this computer, i have just edit the default loading disk.
Laptop model: lenovo legion Y540-15IRH
Monitor: too old, i don't know, it's a very old ACER monitor (in 4/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue disappear.

After few test (with same PC and same monitor), it seems to be a windows update who was bugged. Such as I made all official update day-one, it should come from this.